# Помогите сделать секундомер на Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, gui, ui, fxml

Как сделать графический секудомер и добавить его в оконное приложение?

Comment: раз вопросы был задан 10 часов назад и до сих пор нет ответа, значит не я один не понял вопроса))
что именно вы хотите сделать? может нарисуйте или подробнее опишите

Comment: полностью правил вопрос

Comment: Это слишком широкий вопрос, чтобы на него можно было здесь ответить. Старайтесь думать и читать сами и задавайте боле конкретные вопросы. Почитайте вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: набросал мини-проект секундомер. куда вам его отправить?

Comment: danyamotsniy@gmail.com Спасибо огромное, выручили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ дан на почту ТС'а 1234567